# Adding css style to a specific list element

Tags: html, css, list, css-selectors

Trying to add a top & bottom `border` to the first element of the following menu, but the style also is added to the sub level items with `a`, what I don´t want to archive.

I used CSS as follows:

```
ul.menu--level-0 li.item--level-0 a {}
```

Can anyone help me out please?

```html
<ul class="menu--list menu--level-0 columns--4" style="width: 100%;">
  <li class="menu--list-item item--level-0" style="width: 100%">
    <a href="/boden/sockelleisten/" class="menu--list-item-link" title="Sockelleisten">Sockelleisten</a>
    <ul class="menu--list menu--level-1 columns--4">
      <li class="menu--list-item item--level-1">
        <a href="/boden/sockelleisten/weisse-sockelleisten/" class="menu--list-item-link" title="Weisse Sockelleisten">Weisse Sockelleisten</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu--list-item item--level-1">
        <a href="/boden/sockelleisten/altberliner-hamburger-profil/" class="menu--list-item-link" title="Altberliner / Hamburger Profil">Altberliner / Hamburger Profil</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu--list-item item--level-1">
        <a href="/boden/sockelleisten/echtholz-furnierte-sockelleisten/" class="menu--list-item-link" title="Echtholz Furnierte Sockelleisten">Echtholz Furnierte Sockelleisten</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu--list-item item--level-1">
        <a href="/boden/sockelleisten/massivholzleisten/" class="menu--list-item-link" title="Massivholzleisten">Massivholzleisten</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu--list-item item--level-1">
        <a href="/boden/sockelleisten/mdf-sockelleisten/" class="menu--list-item-link" title="MDF Sockelleisten">MDF Sockelleisten</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu--list-item item--level-1">
        <a href="/boden/sockelleisten/rohrverkleidung-kabelkanaele/" class="menu--list-item-link" title="Rohrverkleidung / Kabelkanäle">Rohrverkleidung / Kabelkanäle</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

Comment: why don't you add a class and then solve your problem

Comment: Thx for answer, because the menu is completely set up via php deep in the shopsystem, I don´t want to change something inside those files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`immediate child selector`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_gt.asp) like this:

```
ul.menu--level-0 > li.item--level-0 a > {}
```

See demo below:

```css
ul.menu--level-0 > li.item--level-0 > a {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px 0;
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu--list menu--level-0 columns--4" style="width: 100%;">
  <li class="menu--list-item item--level-0" style="width: 100%">
    <a href="/boden/sockelleisten/" class="menu--list-item-link" title="Sockelleisten">Sockelleisten</a>
    <ul class="menu--list menu--level-1 columns--4">
      <li class="menu--list-item item--level-1">
        <a href="/boden/sockelleisten/weisse-sockelleisten/" class="menu--list-item-link" title="Weisse Sockelleisten">Weisse Sockelleisten</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu--list-item item--level-1">
        <a href="/boden/sockelleisten/altberliner-hamburger-profil/" class="menu--list-item-link" title="Altberliner / Hamburger Profil">Altberliner / Hamburger Profil</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu--list-item item--level-1">
        <a href="/boden/sockelleisten/echtholz-furnierte-sockelleisten/" class="menu--list-item-link" title="Echtholz Furnierte Sockelleisten">Echtholz Furnierte Sockelleisten</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu--list-item item--level-1">
        <a href="/boden/sockelleisten/massivholzleisten/" class="menu--list-item-link" title="Massivholzleisten">Massivholzleisten</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu--list-item item--level-1">
        <a href="/boden/sockelleisten/mdf-sockelleisten/" class="menu--list-item-link" title="MDF Sockelleisten">MDF Sockelleisten</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu--list-item item--level-1">
        <a href="/boden/sockelleisten/rohrverkleidung-kabelkanaele/" class="menu--list-item-link" title="Rohrverkleidung / Kabelkanäle">Rohrverkleidung / Kabelkanäle</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```